# Background image not filling all of table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following code

```
<table width="930px" height="300px" style="background-image: url('http://www.placekitten.com/200/175'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:930px 300px; border:10px solid #cccccc; ">
  <tr><td height="60px" colspan="2"></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="360px" height="180px" style="background-image: url('img'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:360px 180px; font-family: Trajan; font-size: 50px; color: white; line-height: 80px; " >
      Text
    </td>
    <td width="570px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td height="60px" colspan="2"></td></tr>
</table>
```

And as this JSFiddle shows http://jsfiddle.net/Hw4TJ/ the background image - although it is set to the same size as the table - has a big white strip at the bottom. As the table has a border, this looks rather bad. How to fix?

Answer (score 2):

Problem is different heigh of `<tbody>` and `<table>`, to make it same you need to give css of table to `display:inline-block`

```
<table width="930px" height="300px" style="background-image: url('http://www.placekitten.com/200/175'); background-repeat:no-repeat;
                                           display:inline-block;
                                           background-size:930px 300px; 
                                           border:10px solid #cccccc; ">
<tr><td height="60px" colspan="2"></td></tr>
<tr>
<td width="360px" height="180px" style="background-image: url('img/pc/backgroundv3.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:360px 180px; font-family: Trajan; font-size: 50px; color: white; line-height: 80px; " >
Text
</td>
<td width="570px"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td height="60px" colspan="2"></td></tr>
</table>
```

**[DEMO Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hw4TJ/3/)**

Comment: Ok, that works fine, but it stretches the image. If I just edit the table height a less 14px and left the image at 300px - would that work?

Comment: If you don't want your image to be stretch, you can make it repeat in x direction and specify width to `auto` like, `background-repeat:repeat-x;background-size: auto 300px;`, see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hw4TJ/4/)

Answer (score 1):

take background-size:100% auto;

```
<table width="930px" height="300px" style="background-image: url('http://www.placekitten.com/200/175'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% auto; border:10px solid #cccccc; ">
  <tr><td height="60px" colspan="2"></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="360px" height="180px" style="background-image: url('img'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:360px 180px; font-family: Trajan; font-size: 50px; color: white; line-height: 80px; " >
      Text
    </td>
    <td width="570px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td height="60px" colspan="2"></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The height of the image is too low. try changing the background height to 314px. If you remove the background-repeat attribute from background you can see how the image fit the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="930px" height="300px" style="background-image: url('http://www.placekitten.com/200/175'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:100% 100%; border:10px solid #cccccc; ">
  <tr><td height="60px" colspan="2"></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="360px" height="180px" style="background-image: url('img'); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:360px 180px; font-family: Trajan; font-size: 50px; color: white; line-height: 80px; " >
      Text
    </td>
    <td width="570px"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td height="60px" colspan="2"></td></tr>
</table>
```

just change background size 100%